# Shim for JavaScript .escape function

Tags: javascript, escaping, shim

According to this [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape#wiki-document-head) global `.escape()` function: *'...has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped...'*, as the deprecation notice says. I have some working code heavily relying on that functionality available. Looking at the [es5 escape(string) docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.1) I've put together this piece of code hoping to 'keep the function alive', rather than rewrite the working code I have. **Question is**, of course, is this version doing the same thing as 'soon to be trashed `.escape()` function'? Here's the shim I've came up with:

```
//
// these 69 characters are left as is by native implementation
var safe69chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./";

// equivalent hash map for speeding up character lookup
var chars69  = {0:1,1:1,2:1,3:1,4:1,5:1,6:1,7:1,8:1,9:1,A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,E:1,F:1,G:1,H:1,I:1,J:1,K:1,L:1,M:1,N:1,O:1,P:1,Q:1,R:1,S:1,T:1,U:1,V:1,W:1,X:1,Y:1,Z:1,a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1,e:1,f:1,g:1,h:1,i:1,j:1,k:1,l:1,m:1,n:1,o:1,p:1,q:1,r:1,s:1,t:1,u:1,v:1,w:1,x:1,y:1,z:1,"@":1,"*":1,_:1,"+":1,"-":1,".":1,"/":1};

// these 'percent escapes' map to lower Array<int> list
// and their coresponding (funky) characters are processed by ecape function
var percesc  = "%00%01%02%03%04%05%06%07%08%09%0A%0B%0C%0D%0E%0F%10%11%12%13%14%15%16%17%18%19%1A%1B%1C%1D%1E%1F%20%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2C%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%5B%5C%5D%5E%60%7B%7C%7D%7E%7F%80%81%82%83%84%85%86%87%88%89%8A%8B%8C%8D%8E%8F%90%91%92%93%94%95%96%97%98%99%9A%9B%9C%9D%9E%9F%A0%A1%A2%A3%A4%A5%A6%A7%A8%A9%AA%AB%AC%AD%AE%AF%B0%B1%B2%B3%B4%B5%B6%B7%B8%B9%BA%BB%BC%BD%BE%BF%C0%C1%C2%C3%C4%C5%C6%C7%C8%C9%CA%CB%CC%CD%CE%CF%D0%D1%D2%D3%D4%D5%D6%D7%D8%D9%DA%DB%DC%DD%DE%DF%E0%E1%E2%E3%E4%E5%E6%E7%E8%E9%EA%EB%EC%ED%EE%EF%F0%F1%F2%F3%F4%F5%F6%F7%F8%F9%FA%FB%FC%FD%FE%FF";
var ordesc   = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255];

var isfunc = function (node) {
  return "function" == typeof node;
};

var pad02;
var pad04;


// here check's if it has global .escape, 
// if leaves 'safe69chars' characters unescaped, 
// if correctly escapes other characters, 
// and (re)defines the function if asserts don't pass
if (

  !("escape" in window)  || 
  !isfunc(window.escape) || 
  (safe69chars !== window.escape(safe69chars)) ||
  (percesc !== window.escape(ordesc.map(function(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(c);
  }).join("")))

) {

  pad02 = function(c) {
    //return Array(3).splice(c.length).join("0") + c;
    return (Array(3).splice(c.length).join("0") + c).toUpperCase();
  };

  pad04 = function(c) {
    //return Array(5).splice(c.length).join("0") + c;
    return (Array(5).splice(c.length).join("0") + c).toUpperCase();
  };

  window.escape = function escape (str) {

    str += '';

    // loops each character 
    // escaping it if needed
    for (
      var 
        chr, chrcode, hexcode, i = -1,
        len = str.length, escaped = "";
        ++i < len;
    ) {

      chr = str.charAt(i);

      // use hash lookup to speed up search a bit
      if (chars69.hasOwnProperty(chr)) {

        // if it's in chars69 append it
        escaped += chr;

      } else {

        // get the character's code and it's hex value
        chrcode = chr.charCodeAt(0);
        hexcode = chrcode.toString(16);

        if (chrcode < 256) {

          // pad with '0', length 2 if less than 256 and append
          escaped += ('%' + pad02(hexcode));

        } else {

          // pad with '0', length 4 otherwise and append
          escaped += ('%u' + pad04(hexcode));

        }

      }

    }

    return escaped;
  };

}
//?
//
```

Comment: Why can't you use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` to replace `escape()`?

Comment: because of [encodeURIComponent known bugs](https://www.google.rs/search?q=encodeuricomponent+bug&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gws_rd=cr&ei=YKplU_O9JOy70wWl4oDYDg#channel=sb&q=encodeuricomponent%20bug%20javascript&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) out there, and `.encodeURI()` is supossed to work on full uri strings.

Comment: Is there a specific bug you're concerned about?  The first one your Google search shows is marked as fixed in 2006.  If you're actually dealing with URLs, I'm surprised you need something different than `encodeURIComponent()` or `encodeURI()` which the rest of the world seems to use just fine so I'm trying to figure out why you want to reinvent the wheel.  A generic Google search about bugs isn't much of an answer for why.  I could come up with some sort of bug on just about every API, yet I don't try to rewrite every API because doing so would time inefficient and probably introduce more bugs

Comment: for example this [mdn fixedEncodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description) relies on escape function, and as per this [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description) _encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded..._

Comment: Yeah, and `encodeURIComponent()` does encode those characters.  I still don't understand what you're actually trying to do, but maybe you aren't interested in finding a better way to solve your problem.  Because there are delimiters in parts of the URL such as `&` that must be treated differently from something in the URL that is data not meant to be a delimiter, no master piece of code can just escape the whole thing properly.  It has to know what is and isn't meant to be a delimiter, something only the person who constructs the URL can actually know and use `encodeURIComponent()` on pieces.

Comment: If you want to know if this generates the exact same output as `escape()` then write yourself a test program that throws all sorts of strings at it (you can mechanically generate thousands of strings with all parts of the character set in it) and compare the output of your function to `escape()`.  That's the only way to really test it.

Answer (score 0):

**@jfriend00**, You're right, it didn't occured to me to run a test. It builds a 2**16 (=65536) character string and runs both versions on it comparing (===) the outputs. Native `.escape()` actualy uperrcases hex letters(missed that in snippet above). Here it goes:

```
//
//
var safe69chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./";

var pad02 = function(c) {
  return (Array(3).splice(c.length).join("0") + c).toUpperCase();
};

var pad04 = function(c) {
  return (Array(5).splice(c.length).join("0") + c).toUpperCase();
};


function esc (str) {

  str += '';

  for (
    var chr, chrcode, hexcode, i = -1,
      len = str.length, escaped = "";
    ++i < len;
  ) {

    chr = str.charAt(i);

    if (-1 != safe69chars.indexOf(chr)) {
      escaped += chr;
    } else {

      chrcode = chr.charCodeAt(0);
      hexcode = chrcode.toString(16);

      if (chrcode < 256) {
        escaped += ('%' + pad02(hexcode));
      } else {
        escaped += ('%u' + pad04(hexcode));
      }
    }
  }

  return escaped;
}


var mkrange = function (len) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(
    Array(len+1).join("1"), 
    function (one, i) {return i;}
  )
};

var rng = mkrange(Math.pow(2, 16));

// builds 65536 character string
var str = rng.map(function (c) {return String.fromCharCode(c)}).join("");

// runs the test:
esc(str) === escape(str);
// true
//
```